# ActiveMQ + REST + Java environment creation

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I got several questions regarding this issue

1) ActiveMQ after installed and started also starts Jetty? Jetty is running on port 80?
(the environment where my application is going to be installed already running Apache, so there can't be another web server on port 80...)

2) I have managed successfully post and get messages from queue using java on my machine using following url: http://localhost:8161/demo/message/FOO/BAR. Application will be running on remote machine, where only port 80 is opened.. Is it possible with JAX-RS to create restful web service, which is going to serve queue content on port 80 when I'm just going to access for example the following url: /demo/message/FOO/BAR ?

3) Is there a lot of complex configuration needed to be done on web.xml of ActiveMQ or another files to make this working?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveMQ installation includes a Web Console that can be used to monitor the queue. This is likely what you see when Jetty starts on port 80.

For reference, see [Monitoring ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-MonitoringActiveMQ) and [Web Console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html). The latter link shows how you can configure the Web Console to listen on different ports.

In addition, you could always re-configure ActiveMQ so that the queue listens on port 80 rather than 8161 if you have some requirement that only port 80 of the server can be open.

Comment: OK I'm going to try to configure the queue to listen on port 80 and I'll report my progress ;)